Android Studio will not attach a debugger if the preview is open
If I try to debug a project while the preview is open for Composables (Split - Alt+Shift+Right), the debugger fails to connect. I have to close the split (click the code button) to run the code.
Why is it doing this, and is it supposed to?
IIRC, I did not initially have this problem, but I started having it soon after, and it took me a few hours to figure out it was because I had the preview open.
Maybe, in fact, it was always a problem, but if I'm not in a composable preview source code and the preview split is not showing, then it will work. But, if I'm using the preview a lot, then I constantly run into the problem as I shift between designing with the preview and then testing on the emulator. It seems the preview is using the same port as the emulator (my best guess).
